# Array of files in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

How to define a list of files in Swagger?

Here is what I did but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Do you use `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`?

Comment: i'm using `swagger: '2.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### OpenAPI 2.0

In OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`), you have to define each file as a separate parameter. This means you can only describe requests that send a *fixed*/*limited* number of files. There is no way to define an unbound array of files.

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: file1
          type: file
        - in: formData
          name: file2
          type: file
        - ...
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0

Arrays of files are [supported](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/#multiple) in OpenAPI 3.0. The request can be defined as follows:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

paths:
  /something:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                # "reports" will be used as the name of each file part/field
                # in the multipart request
                reports:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
```

#### OpenAPI 3.1

OAS 3.1 also supports file arrays, but the syntax is slightly different from 3.0. Specifically, file arrays use `items: {}` instead of binary string items.

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0

paths:
  /something:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                # "reports" will be used as the name of each file part/field
                # in the multipart request
                reports:
                  type: array
                  items: {}
```